# Python - ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) - Regular Expressions

Tags: python, html, expression, screen-scraping

I've created regular expressions that scrape data from a HTML file, where I have created if statements that store the output into a list where I can specifically target each element within the list to write a new HTML file. Currently, when `headingList[0]` is called, it outputs correctly with no errors. The code is the exact same for `descriptionList` and `imageList`, however i'm getting `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` for both `descriptionList` and `imageList.`I don't see what the problem is? [The HTML i'm scraping from](https://pastebin.com/QH51UnNL). My code:

```
def extractNews():
selection = listbox.curselection()

if selection == (0,):

    response = urlopen("file:///E:/University/IFB104/InternetArchive/Archives/Sun,%20October%201st,%202017.html")
    html = response.read()
    html = str(html)
    whitespace = "\r\n\t"
    html = html.strip(whitespace)


    heading = findall((r'<h2 class="post-title"><a href="(.*?)".*?>(.*?)</a></h2>'), str(html))
    #image = findall((r'<span data-omni-sm-delegate="(.*?)">(\n|\r)\s+<a href="(.*?)></a>(\n|\r)\s+</span>'), str(html))  #<span data-omni-sm-delegate="(.*)">(\n|\r)\s+<a href="(.*)></a>(\n|\r)\s+</span>
    description = findall((r'<p class="excerpt">(.*?)<a'), str(html))
    storyLink = findall((r'<h2 class="post-title"><a href="(.*?)".*?>(.*?)</a></h2>'), str(html))
    date = findall((r'<time datetime="(.*?)"'), str(html))  # <div class="byline">(r"\n")\s+<time datetime="(.*?)" class="timestamp">(r"\n")\s+(.*)</time>
    print(description)
    #print(date)
    #print(heading)
    #print(image)
    #print(description)



    # if heading:
    #     headingList = []
    #     for link, title in heading:
    #         headingVariable = "%s" % (title)
    #         headingList.append(headingVariable)
    #
    #     print(headingList[0])
    # if image:
    #     imageList = []
    #     for link, title in image:
    #         imageVariable = "%s" % (title)
    #         imageList.append(imageVariable)

    if description:
        descriptionList = []
        for link, title in description:
            descriptionVariable = "%s" % (title)
            descriptionList.append(descriptionVariable)
    print(descriptionList[0])


    # if storyLink:
    #     storyLinkList = []
    #     for link, title in storyLink:
    #         storyLinkVariable = "%s" % (title)
    #         storyLinkList.append(storyLinkVariable)
    #
    # if date:
    #     dateList = []
    #     for link, title in date:
    #         dateVariable = "%s" % (title)
    #         dateList.append(dateVariable)




    # html_str = ('<!DOCTYPE html>\n'
    # '<html>\n'
    # '<head>\n'
    # '<title>TechCrunch Archive - Sun, October 1st, 2017</title>\n'
    # '</head>\n'
    # '<body>\n'
    # '<h1>' + headingList[0] + '</h1>\n'
    # #'<a href="'+ imageList[0]+'></a>\n'
    # '<p>'+descriptionList[0]+'</p>\n'
    # '<p>full story link goes here</p>\n'
    # '<p>'+ dateList[0]+'</p>\n'
    # '<br><br>\n'
    # '<h1>' + headingList[1] + '</h1>\n'
    # 'image goes here\n'
    # '<p>description goes here</p>\n'
    # '<p>full story link goes here</p>\n'
    # '<p>date goes here</p>\n'
    # '<br><br>\n'
    # '<h1>' + headingList[2] + '</h1>\n'
    # 'image goes here\n'
    # '<p>description goes here</p>\n'
    # '<p>full story link goes here</p>\n'
    # '<p>date goes here</p>\n'
    # '<br><br>\n'
    # '</body>\n'
    # '</html>)')
    #
    # Html_file = open("ExtractedContent/Sun, October 1st, 2017 - Extracted.html", "w")
    # Html_file.write(html_str)
    # Html_file.close()
```

Comment: Just print out `description` and see what the problem is.  Obviously one of the elements contains more than two elements.  So look at it, then once you see what's there you can decide what to do about it.  Just add `print(description)` right after `if description`.

Comment: Yeah it scrapes description properly and stores it in an array I think? It looks like ('contentcontentcontent', 'contentcontentcontent', etc..) 20 times as thats how many descriptions exist. The if/forloop block is supposed to store each of these and append them to a list where I can access it later, but i'm getting the error.

Comment: Well your loop is expecting 2 items in each description, `link` and `title`.  The error you're getting indicates that at least one of the descriptions contains more than 2 items.  You just need to find it (as I described), and decide how you want to handle it.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/gwsksm do you know how I can edit my regex to ignore the characters inside alt? I'm only trying to match the data-src string.

Comment: The best way to do something like this is to use one of the pre-existing HTML parsing libraries, then traverse the parsed content after it's been read.  That makes it easy to examine the tags and attributes that are of interest.  I've used `urllib2` with `HTMLParse`.  There's another one called `lxml`.  Trying to write your own HTML-subset parser will be a never-ending battle to try to catch everything you may encounter.